# Page template is not rendering

Tags: angularjs

I have this configuration

```
  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.form', ['ui.select', 'ngSanitize', 'textAngular'])
      .config(routeConfig);

  /** @ngInject */
  function routeConfig($provide, $stateProvider) {

    $provide.decorator('taOptions', ['taRegisterTool', '$delegate', function(taRegisterTool, taOptions) { // $delegate is the taOptions we are decorating

    taOptions.toolbar = [
        ['pre', 'quote','bold', 'italics', 'underline', 'strikeThrough', 'ul', 'ol', 'redo', 'undo', 'clear','justifyLeft', 'justifyCenter', 'justifyRight', 'indent', 'outdent', 'insertImage','insertLink', 'insertVideo'],
        []
    ];
        return taOptions;
    }]);

    $stateProvider
        .state('form', {
          url: '/form',
          template : '<ui-view autoscroll="true" autoscroll-body-top></ui-view>',
          abstract: true,
          title: 'Form Elements',
          sidebarMeta: {
            icon: 'ion-compose',
            order: 250,
          },
        })
        .state('form.campaigns', {
          url: '/campaigns',
          templateUrl: 'app/pages/form/campaigns/campaigns.html',
          title: 'Campaigns',
          controller: 'CampaignsCtrl',
          sidebarMeta: {
            order: 0,
          },
        })
        .state('form.campaigns.detail', {
          url: '/:label',
          // templateUrl: 'app/pages/form/campaigns/campaigns-details.html',
          templateUrl: 'app/pages/components/mail/detail/mailDetail.html',
          title: 'Campaign and Questions1',
          controller: "MailListCtrl",
          controllerAs: "listCtrl"
        })
```

no in file `campaigns.html` i have a link like `<p class="bold grey" ui-sref="form.campaigns.detail({id: '123', label: 'aaa'})">CLICK</p>`.

Now when i am clicking 'CLICK' just the title of page is changing to `Campaign and Questions1` but the template url is still the same i.e `campaign.html` instead of `mailDetail.html`

Comment: Did you checked console for any route errors?

Comment: there is no error in console

Answer (score 0):

try this below ng-view because ui-view use in ui-router and ng-view use  angularjs default router, (if are you using ui-view then you have to install ui-router

```
  template : '<ng-view autoscroll="true" autoscroll-body-top></ng-view>',
```